# Executable-text-files Option missing on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / GNOME 42.0

Tags: nautilus, files, executable, sh

SH files should be executed when double-clicking, instead of being opened in a Text Editor, e.g. Gedit. One can assumingly change this behavior through option "Executable Text Files" in Files, but this option is no longer available, at least in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / GNOME 42.0.

[image]

Comment: No longer available indeed due to upstream Gnome changes.

Comment: So if no longer available, how to configure SH files to  be executed when double-clicking, instead of being opened in a Text Editor ?